# multiple DB backups using a variable name

Tags: sql-server

I have the current script to backup the 3 databases in use (All 3 DB are inter linked). What I would like to do is set the name to be used as a variable which is used for each db backup (rather than changing it 3 times before each execution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
BACKUP DATABASE DB1
TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DB1\TC1\STEP_10.bak' -- Amend the filename
  WITH FORMAT,
  MEDIANAME = 'C_Program Files_Microsoft SQL Server_MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER_MSSQL_Backup',
  NAME = 'DB1';
GO
USE GATEKEEPER_ELEC;
BACKUP DATABASE GATEKEEPER_ELEC
TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DB2\TC1\STEP_10.bak' -- Amend the filename
   WITH FORMAT,
   MEDIANAME = 'C_Program Files_Microsoft SQL Server_MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER_MSSQL_Backup',
   NAME = 'DB2';
GO
USE PFV;
BACKUP DATABASE PFV
    TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\DB3\TC1\STEP_10.bak' -- Amend the filename
  WITH FORMAT,
  MEDIANAME = 'C_Program Files_Microsoft SQL Server_MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER_MSSQL_Backup',
  NAME = 'DB3';
```

Comment: You *don't* need either `GO` or the `USE Database;` commands. You don't need to change the current database in order to issue a `BACKUP` command. Just write the three BACKUP statements and run them

Comment: If you want a more convenient script, check [Ola Hallengren's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html). They allow you to use a single command to backup multiple databases using common parameters like compression, verification, target folders